# SAXParserFactory secure processing feature not working in jboss server

Tags: java, servlets, jboss, saxparser, xxe

I am running the below code snippet to enable secure processing feature and Its working fine in rest API using tomcat server. But this same code snippet is not working using JBoss server.

Please suggest any workaround/fix as I have to fix `XXE injection`.

```java
String strXmlRequest ="<?xml version="1.0"?><!DOCTYPE test[ <!ENTITY demo SYSTEM "D:\\test.text">]>"
SAXParserFactory saxFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
saxFactory.setFeature(XMLConstants.FEATURE_SECURE_PROCESSING, true);

SAXParser saxParser = saxFactory.newSAXParser();
saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(strXmlRequest)), handler );
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try :

```
  saxFactory.setFeature("http://xml.org/sax/features/external-general-entities", false); 
  saxFactory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
```

as explain by [OWASP XXE Prevention sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/XML_External_Entity_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html)